# How to show FirstFragment visuals while using DrawerLayout?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I am coding on a DrawerLayout on **activity_main.xml** but my visuals are on **fragment_first.xml**. I currently am referencing that fragment somehow with this:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:defaultNavHost="true"
  app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

but having finished my DrawerLayout, I cannot select my icons on the drawer without deleting the `<fragment..../>` code, which eliminates my background visuals.

Cannot click on icons:

[image: Cannot click on icons]

Is there a way to keep both the visuals being referenced from `fragment_first` while enabling icon selection?

Here is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start"

>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested by putting

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

above the LinearLayout and it worked. Simple fix.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start"

>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```